# remove data when uninstall plugin joomla

Tags: joomla-4.x

I created content plugin to extend category option. This plguin could add second image to category, it works well. But when I uninstall this plugin, the image is still in the database.

What I want is: the data is also removed when the plugin is uninstalled. How?

I created 3 files:

1. categorydrawing.php
2. categorydrawing.xml
3. categorydrawingimage.xml

Code in categorydrawing.php

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined ('_JEXEC') or die;
class plgContentCategoryDrawing extends JPlugin
{
    /**
     * Load the language file on instantiation.
     * Note this is only available in Joomla 3.1 and higher.
     * If you want to support 3.0 series you must override the constructor
     *
     * @var boolean
     * @since <1.0>
     */
    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;
    /**
     * Prepare form and add my field.
     *
     * @param   JForm  $form  The form to be altered.
     * @param   mixed  $data  The associated data for the form.
     *
     * @return  boolean
     *
     * @since   <1.0>
     */
    function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)
    {
        $app    = JFactory::getApplication();
        $option = $app->input->get('option');
        switch($option)
        {
            case 'com_categories' :
                if ($app->isClient('administrator'))
                {
                    JForm::addFormPath(__DIR__);
                    $form->loadFile('categorydrawingimage', false);
                }
                return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

?>
```

Codes in categorydrawing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="plugin" group="content" method="upgrade">
    <name>Category Drawing</name>
    <description>To add drawing to category</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="categorydrawing">categorydrawing.php</filename>
        <filename>categorydrawingimage.xml</filename>
    </files>
</extension>
```

Codes in categorydrawingimage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="drawing_image_short_description" label="Drawing Image and Description">

                <field
                    name="drawing_image"
                    type="media"
                    label="Drawing Image"
                />

                <field
                    name="drawing_image_alt"
                    type="text"
                    label="Drawing Image Description (Alt Text)"
                />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
    </config>
</form>
```

Comment: What codes I should put in script.php？ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an Installer script that is run when your Plugin is uninstalled that removes the extra data you have added with your plugin.

I couldn't find a Joomla 4 example but these articles for Joomla 3 should get you started, https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file/en and https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/J3.2:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file#helloworld.xml and https://docs.joomla.org/Extension_Installer/Installer_Hooks

The process involves you creating a `script.php` file that contains an `uninstall` method and within that method you provide the code to remove the extra fields from the `params` field of the `#__category` table. The code that you write would extract the JSON value from `params`, remove your `drawing_image` and `drawing_image_alt` entries and then write the the updated JSON value back to the `params` field.

To make sure the script.php will run when the Plugin is uninstalled you need to define the script to the manifest file of your plugin with the following element.

```
<scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
```

Comment: Hi Irata, could you offer the codes in script.php? thanks